# Can I nest form tag inside form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a situation where I have to nest form tag inside form because of HTML flow but it can't be done. Are there any alternatives for this?

```
                <tr class="first last">
                  <td class="a-right last" colspan="50"><button onclick="setLocation('#')" class="button btn-continue" title="Continue Shopping" type="button"><span>Continue Shopping</span></button>
                    <%= button_tag class: 'button btn-update', id: 'update-button' do %>
                      <%= Spree.t(:update) %>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= form_tag empty_cart_path, method: :put do %>
                      <%= submit_tag Spree.t(:empty_cart), class: 'button btn-empty' %>
                    <% end %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>

          <%= form_for @order, url: update_cart_path, html: { id: 'update-cart' } do |order_form| %>

            <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { order_form: order_form } %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

button_tag should be inside form_for form, but if I set it like this:

```
                <td class="a-right last" colspan="50"><button onclick="setLocation('#')" class="button btn-continue" title="Continue Shopping" type="button"><span>Continue Shopping</span></button>
                    <%= form_for @order, url: update_cart_path, html: { id: 'update-cart' } do |order_form| %>
                    <%= button_tag class: 'button btn-update', id: 'update-button' do %>
                      <%= Spree.t(:update) %>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= form_tag empty_cart_path, method: :put do %>
                      <%= submit_tag Spree.t(:empty_cart), class: 'button btn-empty' %>
                    <% end %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>


            <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { order_form: order_form } %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

it's not working

Answer (score 1):

> Can I nest form tag inside form?

You cannot nest form tags.

It is wrong. It won't work because it is wrong. Most browsers will only see one form.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

> Content model:
>   Flow content, but with **no form element descendants**.

Comment: thanks for replying. Do you have any tip to resolve this kind of problem from above?

Comment: dont use nested forms, use links, modals etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct you like to have that empty_cart button aligned with your update button. In Rails you can create a link that does an update or post or whatever you like. You can do something like:

```
<%= link_to Spree.t(:empty_cart(_method: 'put')), empty_cart_path, class: 'button btn-empty', method: :post %>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to leave button_tag for update path exactly where it is(outside from form_for @order). I tried with  <%= link_to  Spree.t(:update), update_cart_path, class: 'button btn-update', id: 'update-button', method: :put %> and I get No route matches [PUT] "/cart"

Comment: In that case you could simply move the 'form_tag empty_cart_path' block out of the 'form_for @order' block it is now nested inside which is not possible. Strange the form_tag empty_cart_path, method: :put also has method put are you missing that route in your routes file?

Comment: Ah this routing issue I think the method should be :post instead of :put but you need to set a parameter named _method to put. Let me edit my Answer.